# Ajax loading content wont work if link is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax script that replaces my #main content with a loaded page depending on the link

Example: rddd would replace #main and replace it with the contents of about.php

Though my problem is that it is working fine and everything other then if I have a link inside about.php example lala.php and then I get it to load up [by pressing another link like we did with the about.php above], I can't load the lala.php link up in ajax instead it takes me to the page instead of replacing #main.

I've tried a lot of things even copied the exact code over from the navigation, still won't work. It will work everywhere else other then inside #main

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#ajax a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #main';
            $('#main').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });


    $('#ajax a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main';
        $('#main').fadeOut('normal',loadmain);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadmain() {
            $('#main').load(toLoad,'',showNewmain())
        }
        function showNewmain() {
            $('#main').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle to look at issue you face.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj doesnt really help. http://jsfiddle.net/tHdjk/

Comment: ugghhhh need to fix this somehow

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the event handlers. When your `$('#ajax a').click()` functions run, they bind event handlers **only to the elements that already exist** . Thus, your Ajax loader works for the link to the about page - the event handler fires - but not for the links on the about page. They weren't part of the DOM when your event handlers were created.

You can fix this by changing your event handlers to listen on the document, instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ajax a', function() { 
    // Callback function here.
});
```